# which http verb/best practice to update an entity without payload to send?

Tags: rest, payload

purpose is really simple:
i want to modify entities but i have no data to send in payload, as request is really easy.
In fact, my url is something like :

```
/v1/{customerId}/release/old/subscriptions
```

==> the code update entity Subscription for customerId asked.

the question is:
    @GetMapping : ok but is not RESTFULL as entity is modified!
    @PutMapping : ok but no payload to send !
    @PostMapping : ok but no payload to send !

what is best practice ?

i want to do some

Comment: you don't need a payload. If it adds something use PUT, if it updates use POST

Comment: [PATCH](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc5789) is appropriate for *partial* modifications to a resource. This [article](https://blog.cloud-elements.com/http-verbs-demystified-patch-put-and-post) has a reasonable explanation.

Comment: perfect. implemented with PATCH verb, with no payload. seems to be most coherent with restfull norm.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> which http verb/best practice to update an entity without payload to send?

The general rule is that you use POST *unless* the semantics of your message match a more specific method.

[PUT](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-4.3.4) with an empty payload is a request to make the current representation of the resource zero bytes long.  Think "delete the contents of the file".

[PATCH](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5789) requests are supposed to include a patch-document in the payload; and so the meaning would be whatever an empty document of that particular media type means.  I don't think I've ever heard of a case where an empty patch document does something interesting.

[POST](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-4.3.3) requests are intended for any semantic that [isn't worth standardizing](https://roy.gbiv.com/untangled/2009/it-is-okay-to-use-post).